# Laravel PDOException(code: 1045) yet credentials work in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, laravel-6

An PDOException(code: 1045) error occurs when laravel connects to mysql yet the credentials allow me to log in via phpmyadmin suggesting the credentials are correct.

Error message:

```
(PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'host.domain.com'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=host.domain.com
DB_USERNAME=host.domain.com
DB_PASSWORD=password_here
```

PHP version is 7.2.31
Laravel Framework version is 6.13.1
CentOS server (note cant make the error occur on my Windows laptop with WAMP)

Answer (score 0):

If I quoted the DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD fields in .env the application worked. I have no further explanation of why considering there are no spaces in the values for these fields.

Revised .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE="host.domain.com"
DB_USERNAME="host.domain.com"
DB_PASSWORD="password_here"
```

Comment: probably a punctuation character in the password

Comment: @YourCommonSense. an underscore and a hash otherwise letters and numbers.  Just FYI :)

Comment: so how do you think, could a hash have some special meaning in the configuration file?

Comment: @YourCommonSense doh! yep :)